# Express SessionID not persistent, no browser cookie

Tags: angularjs, node.js, cookies, express

I'm trying to setup a simple passport login using node, express and angular. I'm having trouble getting sessions to persist, I think because it's not setting a browser cookie, but why?

There's no cookie set in my browser, and the sessionID recognized by node is different every request.

This is using Express 4, which seems pretty significantly different from Exp3. I think it may have something to do with middlware ordering or session storage configuration. I'm trying to get away with default handling, which I think is MemoryStore in Exp4, but It doesn't seem to be working.

Also, I should mention that the static HTML/CSS are served by apache, not node. Node is just setup for API calls.

Here are the relevant lines from package.json.

```
"dependencies": {
    "bcrypt-nodejs": "0.0.3",
    "body-parser": "^1.10.1",
    "connect-flash": "^0.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.3.3",
    "express": "^4.11.0",
    "express-session": "^1.10.1",
    "mongoose": "^3.8.21",
    "morgan": "^1.5.1",
    "passport": "^0.2.1"
  }
```

And the middleware setup

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var passport = require('passport');
var flash    = require('connect-flash');
var app = express();

var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var session = require('express-session');
```

...

```
app.use(morgan('dev')); // log every request to the console
app.use(cookieParser()); // read cookies (needed for auth)

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.use(session({
  secret: 'DGUBJH7H6G6GTF5R53R54RSBH',
  resave: true,
  saveUninitialized: true
}));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(flash());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");
  res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept");
  next();
});

require('./config/routes.js')(app, passport);
```

The Routes

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local-login'), function(req, res) {
    var user = req.user;
    res.send(user);
  });
app.get('/user', isLoggedIn, function (req, res) {
    var user = req.user;
    res.send(user);
  });
function isLoggedIn(req, res, next) {
  var user = req.user;
  // if user is authenticated in the session, carry on
  if (req.isAuthenticated())
    return next();

  res.status(403).send();
}
```

I could also post the passport code with the serialize and deserialize functions, but I'm not sure they're relevant for this. I just need to figure out why this code isn't setting browser cookies! Any Help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main problem here for me was that I was doing my login call asynchronously with angular's $http service. It seems that most browsers wont set a cookie based on the header of an asynchronous request. I changed My login form to point directly to my node login callback and now it does a page reload in order to set the cookie, then immediately redirects to the main page of my app.

Answer (score 0):

Here, you are only setting the session but not setting the cookie. So, try to set the cookie

```
// configuration
app.use(express.cookieParser());
// or  `express.cookieParser('secret')` for signed cookies

// routing
app.get('/foo', function (req, res) {
    res.cookie('bar', 'baz');
`});

app.get('/bar', function (req, res) {
    res.send(req.cookies.bar);
});
```

Comment: I'm talking specifically about session cookies, which I'm hoping would be handled by the session middleware if I'm not mistaken. Is it normal to have to have to set your own session cookies even when using all this middleware?